# Entity framework code first reference many models to one model

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

How to reference many models(Lesson, Set)
to one model (File)

```
public class File
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Path { get; set; }
}

public class Lesson
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual File File { get; set; }
}

public class Set
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual List<File> Files { get; set; }
}
```

I try to put int File table an ForigenKey but then there is Duplicate problem between Lesson to set

Any Idea?

Comment: Are you getting an error with the migration or using the context with real data. Might help to see that code.

Comment: I still trying to understand your objective, do you want File to be referenced by only one Lesson, like a unique index? the same with Set? A File cannot be part of different Sets?

Comment: Look for *polymorphic associations*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still trying to understand your objective, do you want File to be referenced by only one Lesson, like a unique index? the same with Set? A File cannot be part of different Sets? if yes, i would add a Index To Lesson and for Set, i would create another class and also add a Index. Something like this:

```
public class File
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Path { get; set; }           
}

public class Lesson
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("File")]
    [Index("IX_UniqueLessonFileId", IsUnique =true)]
    public int FileID { get; set; }

    public virtual File File { get; set; }
}

public class Set
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SetFile> Files { get; set; }
}
public class SetFile
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Set")]
    public int SetId {get;set;}
    public virtual Set Set { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("File")]
    [Index("IX_UniqueSetFileId", IsUnique =true)]       
    public int FileId {get;set;}
    public virtual File File { get; set; }
}
```